# AFNetworking - Using Serializers

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to setup a basic API request using `AFNetworking` in Objective C.  However, I'm a little confused about how the `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` is supposed to work.  As of now, the below code doesn't seem to execute a request to my API, as nothing is printed in either the success / error `NSLog` statements.  I don't think I understand exactly how `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` is incorporated into `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`:

```
    NSString *URLString = @"http://mysite.dev/v1/user/5";
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"include": @"places"};

    manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc]
               initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];

    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

    // Do I need to return this? Or does AFHTTPRequestOperationManager
    // use this implicitly within its request?
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer
        requestWithMethod:@"GET"
        URLString:URLString
        parameters:parameters
        error:nil
    ];

    // My oAuth Header token
    [manager.requestSerializer  setValue:@"1234" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest: request
            success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
            } 
            failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError * error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following function it works for me. I settle out `Header Value` and used `requestSerializer`

```
- (void)getServerRequest:(NSString *)strRequestURL {

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Header1Value" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Header1Key"];

    [manager GET:@"URL String" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"success: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

}
```

Comment: yep, thats more or less what I ended up doing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand, it seems that `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest` is used for creating asynchronous requests.  However, it doesn't actually add them to the queue, it only creates the request object -- which is why i was receiving no output.

Instead, I'm now using `[manager GET]`.